# Prove that $|x-a|<b\Rightarrow x>a-2b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove the following, $$|x-a|<b\Rightarrow x>a-2b?$$

Comment: $a - 2b < a - b < x < b + a$

Comment: @user236182, are you saying $b$ could be anything but $b > 0$?

Comment: @user236182, is $b$ not assumed to be so? $0 \leq |x - a| < b$? Or am I missing something here...?

Comment: By definition, this is not an axiom if there exists a proof for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $|x-a|<b$ is equivalent to $-b<x-a<b$, so $x>a-b$.

If $b>0$, this implies $x>a-2b$, because $a-b>a-2b$.

If $b\le0$, the statement $|x-a|<b$ is false for every $x$, so the statement $|x-a|<b$ implies anything, in particular $x>a-2b$.

Comment: @user236182 Where is it said that $b>0$? The statement to be proved is “for all $x$, if $|x-a|<b$, then $x>a-2b$”.